# Complete category reduces to preordered class

Tags: category-theory

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category such that for every category
> $\mathcal{D}$ and every functor $F:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$,
> the functor $F$ has a limit. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a preordered class.

In order to prove this, we must show that, for every $X,Y\in\mathcal{C}$, the set $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ has at most one element.

Suppose there exist $X,Y\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ and $f\ne g$. Let $\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})$ be the arrow category of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\Delta_Y:\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ be the constant functor on $Y$. By assumption, there exist $L\in\mathcal{C}$ and a family of morphisms $(p_u:L\rightarrow Y)_{u\in\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ such that
$$p_{u'}=\Delta_Y(h,k)\circ p_u=1_Y\circ p_u=p_u$$
for $(h,k):u\rightarrow u'$.

The next step is to show that the cardinality of the set
$$A:=\left\{(M,(q_u)_{u\in\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})})\ |\ \forall u,\,q_u:M\rightarrow Y\land\forall(u\rightarrow u'), q_u=q_{u'}\right\}$$
is $\geq2^{\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$. ($A$ is supposed to be the set of cones on $\Delta_Y$.)

But: (i) Why should $A$ be a set? (ii) Even if it is a set, how can I  show that $|A|\geq2^{\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$? I already know that I can use $f$ and $g$ to construct two cones on $\Delta_Y$.

**Edit:**

Is every pair $(M,q)\in\{X\}\times\{f,g\}^{\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ a cone on $\Delta_Y$? Take $q\in\{f,g\}^{\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$. Let $(h,k):u\rightarrow u'$. If $q_u=f$ and $q_{u'}=g$, then we cannot have
$$q_u=\Delta_Y(h,k)\circ q_{u'}$$
because that would imply $f=g$. So arbitrary $(M,q)\in\{X\}\times\{f,g\}^{\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ cannot be a cone..

**Edit 2:**

Can some please explain why there are at least $2^{\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ distinct cones on $\Delta_Y$? How can I use $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ and $(p_u:L\rightarrow Y)_{u\in\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ to construct cones on $\Delta_Y$? (I know that the constant classes of morphisms $(f)_{u\in\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ and $(g)_{u\in\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ together with $X$ constitute two cones.)

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043557/why-is-every-category-in-which-all-even-large-limits-and-colimits-exist-thin) thread or p. 59 of _Handbook of categorical algebra: I_ by F. Borceux :)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I still don't understand why there must be at least $2^{\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ distinct cones on $\Delta_Y$. The answer posted in the other thread just asserts it...There is probably some basic justification for this. I am just not able to see it. Can you explain why there at least $2^{\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ distinct cones on $\Delta_Y$?

Comment: If you have a collection of maps $\{f_i\mid i\in I\}$ from $A\to B$, then you get an arrow $A\to \prod_I B$. Each $f_i$ can take _at least_ two values, so you have _at least_ $2^I$ arrows from $A$ to $\prod_I B$. Then take $I$ big enough (all the arrows in your category) to get a contradiction.

Comment: @PawełCzyż I am sorry but I am still confused..Let's try something else. Let $X,Y$ be two sets and $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ two mappings such that $f\ne g$. For every set $J$, how can I show that $2^{|J|}\leq|(\prod_{j\in J}Y|^{|X|}$? i.e. that there are at least $2^{|J|}$ mappings $X\rightarrow\prod_{j\in J}Y$? Can you tell me how I can construct these maps from $X$ to $\prod_{j\in J}Y$? I am not sure if this example is appropriate. I only want to know the procedure of constructing the cones on $\Delta_Y$ from $f$ and $g$.

Comment: If you have a family of maps $X\to Y$, you get a unique map $X \to \prod Y$ making appropriate diagram commute. Then you just take enough families to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of your confusion is that you are trying to use the arrow category $\operatorname{Arr}(\mathcal{C})$, while you should just take the $\operatorname{Arr}(\mathcal{C})$-fold product of $Y$. Let's denote by $\operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})$ the discrete category of arrows in $\mathcal{C}$. So it is just the collection of arrows in $\mathcal{C}$. The product that we are interested in is
$$
\prod_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})} Y.
$$

Let's assume for a moment that $\mathcal{C}$ is small. So $\operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set and its powerset $2^{\operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ makes sense. For any $U \subseteq \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})$ we can define a cone $(X, p_u)_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ as follows:
$$
p_u = \begin{cases}
f & \text{if } u \in U \\
g & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
As per your notation $f$ and $g$ are the distinct arrows $X \to Y$. So there is an injection from subsets of $\operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})$ to the collection of cones on our product diagram. By the universal property there is a bijective correspondence between these cones and arrows $X \to \prod_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})} Y$. We thus find injections
$$
2^{\operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})} \hookrightarrow
\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X, \prod_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})} Y) \subseteq
\operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C}),
$$
contradicting Cantor's theorem on the cardinality of a powerset.

This trick still works even if $\mathcal{C}$ is not small. One way to easily fix it is to just use universes. So $\operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set in some bigger universe. If you are uncomfortable with such foundational assumptions, we can just unfold Cantor's argument.

So now we no longer assume $\mathcal{C}$ is small (not even in some bigger universe). Denote by $\pi_u: \prod_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})} Y \to Y$ the projection on the $u$ coordinate. Define a cone $(X, q_u)_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ on our product diagram as follows. For $u \not \in \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X, \prod_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})} Y)$ we set $q_u = f$ (we don't really care about this part of the cone). For $u \in \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X, \prod_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})} Y)$ we set
$$
q_u = \begin{cases}
f & \text{if } \pi_u u = g \\
g & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
By the universal property $(X, q_u)_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})}$ corresponds to an arrow $v: X \to \prod_{u \in \operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})} Y$. That means that $q_v = \pi_v v$, which is impossible by how we constructed $q_v$. So we find our contradiction and conclude that there cannot be two parallel distinct arrows.

Comment: Dear Mark, thank you for your help. Would you please clarify the following for me?–Using the discrete arrow category $\text{arr}(\mathcal{C})$ trivializes the cone condition to $p_u=p_u$, correct? (I mean the condition that requires $p_{u'}=\Delta_Y(u\rightarrow u')\circ p_u$ for $u\rightarrow u'\in\text{arr}(\mathcal{C})$). This condition wouldn't be satisfied if I were to use the arrow category $\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})$ to construct $(p_u)_{u\in\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})}$, would it?...(cont'd)

Comment: ...Using $\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})$, it isn't necessary to have $p_{u'}=\Delta_Y(u\rightarrow u')\circ p_u$ because $u\rightarrow u'$ doesn't force $u=u'$, right? e.g. if $u\in U$ and $u'\not\in U$, then I would get $f=p_u=p_{u'}=g$, contrary to the assumption $f\ne g$.

Comment: @alf262 Indeed, considering the concrete category $\operatorname{arr}(\mathcal{C})$ trivialises the conditions on the cone. If you consider the arrow category, as you did before, it heavily depends on the category $\mathcal{C}$ (namely what commutative squares there are). So not much can be said in general in that case.